# Can't find gem 'rake' after running bundle install

Tags: ruby, bash, rake, bundler, rbenv

*Environment: Bash for Windows 10*

I'm trying to setup a Ruby environment on my workstation from a client repository. I ran `bundle install` to install all the gems in rbenv. I then run `rake`, which was supposed to install during the process and receive an error message. Below are logs I receive when running the commands in bold.

**`bundle exec rake db:create`**

```
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

**`rake`**

```
Could not find rake-10.5.0 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

**`bundle install`**

```
Bundle complete! 31 Gemfile dependencies, 124 gems now installed.
Use `bundle info [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

**`bundle info rake`**

```
  * rake (10.5.0)
        Summary: Rake is a Make-like program implemented in Ruby
        Homepage: https://github.com/ruby/rake
        Path: /usr/share/rubygems-integration/all/gems/rake-10.5.0
```

**`bundle | grep rake`**

`Using rake 10.5.0`

Comment: try `bundle exec rake <command>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try install rake manually to see if it solves your problem, run
`gem install rake -v '10.5.0'`

Comment: That did it! Thanks!